# Click 'OK' button in javascript alert using AutoIT

Tags: testing, webdriver, autoit

I want to handle JavaScript alerts using AutoIt. By using webdriver alert method, I am able to handle alerts in IE but in Firefox I am unable to do so. I opted to use AutoIT. Suggest me if there is any other way to accomplish this.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Why are you not able to handle it? Whats the error ?

Comment: Amey,it's not throwing any error but the alert is still displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use `_FFClick` from the Firefox UDF [FF.au3](http://www.thorsten-willert.de/Themen/FFau3/FF.au3/FF.au3?a) by Thorsten Willert. Just download the AU3 file and save it in the same directory as your AutoIt script, then include it like so:

```
#include "FF.au3"
```